# How do I convert a ssh-keygen public key into a format that openssl PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY() function will consume?

Tags: openssh, openssl

I'm having an issue generating a public key that the openssl `PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY()` function can consume. I keep getting errors.

Obviously I cannot simply use the ASCII string in the `ssh-keygen <>.pub` key file as it is in SSH file format or I perhaps `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` structure.

Here's the key gen code: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 1024 -C "Test Key"`

I found a converter in php on the web which will convert the contents of the public key into a base64 PEM ASCII string format.  However the function still doesn't like it.

The Openssl documentation states:

1. “RSA_PUBKEY() function which process a public key using an EVP_PKEY structure”
2. “RSA_PUBKEY functions also process an RSA public key using an RSA structure”

How do I get my OpenSSH public key into either format that the OpenSSL function will consume it?

Comment: Figured this out: use the openssl tool only as such:

Comment: Create Private key: openssl genrsa -out test.priv.key 2048;   Output Public key in same format (PEM?): openssl rsa -in test.priv.key -pubout -out test.pub.key

Comment: Cross-related https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32768/converting-keys-between-openssl-and-openssh

Answer (score 89):

OK!

So I walked into this thinking "Easy, I got this."  Turns out there's a whole lot more to it than even I thought.

The first issue is that (according to the man pages for OpenSSL, `man 3 pem`), OpenSSL is expecting the RSA key to be in PKCS#1 format. Clearly, this isn't what ssh-keygen is working with.  You have two options (from searching around).

If you have OpenSSH v. 5.6 or later (I did not on my laptop), you can run this:

```
ssh-keygen -f key.pub -e -m pem
```

The longer method of doing this is to break apart your SSH key into its various components (the [blog entry](https://web.archive.org/web/20120124211352/http://blog.oddbit.com/2011/05/converting-openssh-public-keys.html) I found some of this in accuses OpenSSH of being "proprietary", I prefer to call it "unique") and then use an ASN1 library to swap things around.

Fortunately for you, someone wrote the code to do this:

https://gist.github.com/1024558

Comment: The `ssh-keygen` method seems to work on Linux but not Mac OS X.

Comment: Lid, see the note in the answer about SSH version.  OS X doesn't ship a recent version of OpenSSH.  Run the command `ssh -V`.

Comment: Doesn't work in `OpenSSH_6.2p2`. Does work in `OpenSSH_6.6p1`.

Comment: `-m` doesn't work for me ... what is the work around?

Comment: FYI, a few folks have suggested various edits without taking the actual description into context.  I'm happy to update this, but change any technical details which are then conflicting.

Comment: Works for me on mac!

Comment: Drop `-m pem` if you want the resulting key in `BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY` format.

Answer (score 34):

Assuming you have the SSH private key `id_rsa`, you can extract the public key from it like so:

```
openssl rsa -in id_rsa -pubout -out id_rsa.pub.pem
```

I realize the OP asked about converting a public key, so this doesn't quite answer the question, however I thought it would be useful to some anyway.

Note also that this command results in a PEM public key format, which is generally what OpenSSL expects. The answer by Brian, on the other hand, results in a file in RSAPublicKey format, which is not the normal format expected by OpenSSL (though later versions can apparently read it via the `-RSAPublicKey_in` flag). To convert you can do this:

```
openssl rsa -RSAPublicKey_in -in id_rsa.rsapub.pem -pubout -out id_rsa.pub.pem
```

Comment: Thanks, the -pubout from the private key did the trick for me.

Comment: `openssl rsa -in id_rsa.pem -pubout -out id_rsa.pub.pem` also work (i.e. input is pem format private key).  Good answer.

Comment: Update: Brian's answer has been corrected to `-m pkcs8` which in spite of OpenSSH folks using the wrong name _does_ produce X.509 'PUBKEY'. Also, since OpenSSH 6.5 in 2014-01 if the creator specified 'new format' `-o` for better security, this method won't work, and since 7.8 in 2018-08 'new format' is now the default, ditto.

Comment: One liners: `openssl rsa -RSAPublicKey_in -in <(ssh-keygen -e -m pem -f id_rsa.pub) > id_rsa.pub.pem` or `ssh-keygen -e -m pem -f id_rsa.pub | openssl rsa -RSAPublicKey_in > id_rsa.pub.pem`

Answer (score 30):

The format you want is what `ssh-keygen` calls `PKCS8`.  So the following command will produce the desired output:

```
ssh-keygen -f key.pub -e -m pkcs8
```

From the `ssh-keygen` man page:

```
-m key_format
         Specify a key format for the -i (import) or -e (export) conversion 
         options.  The supported key formats are: 
         ``RFC4716'' (RFC 4716/SSH2 public or private key), 
         ``PKCS8'' (PEM PKCS8 public key) or 
         ``PEM'' (PEM public key).  
         The default conversion format is ``RFC4716''.
```

Comment: This one actually works on both Linux and macOS.

Comment: to extract the equivalent generated public key from private key in OpenSSL openssl rsa -in key -pubout -out key.pub.openssl.pkcs8

Comment: `Unsupported conversion format "pksc8"`

Comment: @samayo: You misspelled "pkcs8" by swapping the s and the c.

Answer (score 7):

Similar to Amal Chaudhuri's method below, this is what worked for me. I needed to create a pem file from the ssh public key I'd generated for my SFTP client (Cyberduck).

```
openssl rsa -in ~/.ssh/id_rsa -outform pem > id_rsa.pem
```

Comment: this doesn't actually seem to work.

Comment: This ONLY works for private RSA key NOT the public key OP was asking. So wrong answer.

Comment: Actually, `id_rsa` already is in the right format, you can check it out by yourself, the resulting `id_rsa.pem` is 100% identical.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh-keygen -f path/to/id_rsa.pub -e -m pem > path/to/rsa.pem
```

Here's what each part of the command does:

-f path/to/id_rsa.pub: Specifies the input file, the path to your existing OpenSSH public key file (id_rsa.pub).

-e -m pem: Specifies the format conversion to PEM.

">" path/to/rsa.pem: Redirects the output to a file named rsa.pem in the specified directory (path/to/).

```
ssh-keygen -f id_rsa.pub -e -m pem > yourfilename.pem
```

Answer (score -2):

Another way to do this from another site. Posting this in case you need another method. Works very well.
http://www.chatur.com.np/2011/01/convert-openssh-rsa-key-to-pem-format.html

```
openssl dsa -in ~/.ssh/id_dsa -outform pem > id_dsa.pem
```

Comment: That method doesn't seem to actually work.

Comment: `id_rsa` is not a public key. Wrong answer.